# Not able to compile Groovy code into a java class file

Tags: java, eclipse, grails, groovy

I am trying to implement stand alone GORM in my Java EE application. I have created a Groovy class for domain but my eclipse is not compiling it into java class and GORM is not able to find it.
I have

- Eclipse Helios
- Groovy Eclipse Plugin installed from [here](http://dist.codehaus.org/groovy/distributions/greclipse/snapshot/e3.6/)
- groovyall.jar in my lib folder
- I have Configured my project as Groovy Project.

What else I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the Groovy nature to the project? Is the folder containing the Groovy sources marked as a source folder? Have you selected the correct Groovy version in the Groovy compiler preferences?

Comment: 1- Yes. I did Project->Configure->Convert to Groovy Project 2- In the src folder of my project I created another package and added a Groovy class. Other than that I am not sure how should mark as source folder. 3- My default Eclipse setting shows that I am using Groovy compiler 1.8.6.xx

Comment: Do you see something in the error log (open that view if it isn't already)?