# Bringing Groovy code to the src folder in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy

Groovy code in project structure is **src/groovycode/src/packagename** and rest of the java classes are in src/packagename. My other team member use IntelliJ and it seamlessly compiles groovy classes into java classes with desired package names and ignores groovycode/src folder.
 I am not able to do same in Eclipse and compile groovy classes at all. So I end up copying groovy class from others and copying into my WEB-INF/classes folder.
Is there any way to achieve this in Eclipse?
In between I am using Eclipse Helios and have Groovy Eclipse plugin installed.

Comment: Is this the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333932/not-able-to-compile-groovy-code-into-a-java-class-file with the words in a different order?

Comment: @tim_yates Not exactly. Here I am asking for the folder structure because I have some flex code into src/flec/src/packagename directory which I am not able to compile with flex plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have not set `src/groovycode/src` as a source folder.  You need to right click on the source folder and select Build path -> Use as source folder.  Once you do that you should open up your Java build settings page for the project and set the output folder for that source folder.

I would also recommend that you upgrade to Eclipse Indigo or Juno and start using Groovy-Eclipse 2.7.0.